# How to to praise multiple Youtube channels using Volley

Tags: youtube, android-volley

I'm creating an app for all my clients youtube channels, I'm using volley to praise the channels,

my problem is when I click on any channels it only retrieve one channel, so how can I make the volley understands that it should fetch different channels on click

here is the **code** sample >

ListView channelList;

```
ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsArrayList;
ChannelAdapter channelAdapter;
String channelUrl="";
String channelId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_channel);

    channelList = findViewById(R.id.channelList);
    videoDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    channelAdapter = new ChannelAdapter(ChannelActivity.this,videoDetailsArrayList);

    channelUrl = String.format(getIntent().getStringExtra("channelUrl"), channelId);
    channelId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


    displayVideos();
}

private void displayVideos() {

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, channelUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject jsonVideoId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                    JSONObject jsonObjectSnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");

                    JSONObject jsonObjectDefault = jsonObjectSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                    String video_Id = jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                    VideoDetails vd = new VideoDetails();

                    vd.setVideoId(video_Id);
                    vd.setTitle(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("title"));
                    vd.setDescription(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("description"));
                    vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                    videoDetailsArrayList.add(vd);

                }

                channelList.setAdapter(channelAdapter);
                channelAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    );

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: In `displayVideos` method, there's a `channelUrl`- what is the value in that variable? also, consider check the results of `response` in `onResponse` - maybe you're getting only (1) item. Consider [edit] your question and add the sample data you're requesting, the current data and the desired result.

Comment: hi Marco, thanks so much for your comment, yes i'm getting the results for one channel, my problem is I want to get from different channels , it's like netflix when I click on the channel icon i can get the whole channel, do you know what I mean?

Comment: hi Mohamad, what does `displayVideos` receive? - I think I understand you, but, I believe you're requesting only 1 channel; for multiple channels, you should change the request. I'm not familiar with your code, but, `channelUrl` and `channelId` belongs to a single channel - and you want multiple channels, so, for example: using YouTube Data API, you can use `search` request and specify the response to `channels` only - I don't know what are you using previous for get the values of `channelUrl` and `channelId`

Comment: Hi Marco, yes this is exactly my problem I'm receiving 1 channel and I want multiple channels, ChannelUrl should be be linked to each banner following is the code that I should click to retrive the channel

Comment: originalsBannerList.add(new BannerMovies(1,"test","https://www.beebibelle.com.au/assets/full/Cocomelon_Banner5.png?20200624034528","https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCbCmjCuTUZos6Inko4u57UQ&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyBpb8WQKcAiOepk52vuDm72upK-E-YWMCM"));
        originalsBannerList.add(new BannerMovies(2,"test","https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5143Wwvl5JL._AC_SY400_.jpg","https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCSVSJ1OCSv5ClFgKFTHIDew&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyBpb8WQKcAiOepk52vuDm72upK-E-YWMCM"));

Comment: I get the 1st channel link but the 2nd and 3rd it doesn't retrive them it gives me blank screen

Comment: this is the link I should fetch the channel from [link] https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCbCmjCuTUZos6Inko4u57UQ&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyBpb8WQKcAiOepk52vuDm72upK-E-YWMCM